# How to properly open and read from a StorageFile multiple times?

Tags: c#, file, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) I'm grabbing a file from the user's document folder and trying to read through it twice. Once to read each line and get a count of total line for progress tracking purposes. And the second time to actually parse the data. However, on the second pass I get a "File is not readable" type error. So I have a small understanding of what's going on but not entirely. Am I getting this error because the stream of the file is already at the end of the file? Can't I just open a new stream from the same file, or do I have to close the first stream?

Here's my code:

```
public async Task UploadBerData(StorageFile file)
{
    _csvParser = new CsvParser();
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

    using (var readStream = stream.AsStreamForRead())
    {
        dataCount = _csvParser.GetDataCount(stream.AsStreamForRead());

        // Set the progressBar total to 2x dataCount.
        // Once for reading, twice for uploading data
        TotalProgress = dataCount * 2;
        CurrentProgress = 0;
    }

    var csvData = _csvParser.GetFileData(stream.AsStreamForRead());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After using the `Stream`, the `position` is the end of stream length.
You can set it to beginning to read stream again.

Add following line before your parse data function.

```
stream.Position = 0;
```